# Animator does not contain "IsInTransition"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Based on this [Unity Animator API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html), there's a public function named **IsInTransition**. but why i cannot use it?

When i try to code in *MonoDevelop*, the **Autocompletion** wont work and also build was Error :

```
Assets/Scripts/CatAnimator.cs(32,18): error CS1061: 
Type `Animator' does not contain a definition for `isInTransition' 
and no extension method `isInTransition' 
of type `Animator' could be found. 
Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

any idea ?

The Complete Code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animator : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator myAnimator;

    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    CharacterController controller;
    float currSpeed, Param1;
    bool Param2, Param3;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
        myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Param1 = 0;
        Param2 = false;
        Param3 = false;
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
        //==
        }

        if (myAnimator.IsInTransition (0)) { //ERROR HERE...

        }
    }//==update
}//==class
```

Comment: But whats the code?

Comment: @Hristo wait a sec, i will add

Comment: It says in the Unity manual: `IAnimatorControllerPlayable.IsInTransition`. And also about that it says: _Experimental: this API is experimental and might be changed or removed in the future_.

Comment: @Hristo so this has removed, but no notification. i type this code from Book Published in 2015...

Comment: Another thing your class is named `Animator` and you are creating an object `Animator` in your class. when you call `myAnimator.IsInTransition` its actually looking in your `Animator` class for a function/propery called `IsInTransition`

Comment: And that does not exist

Comment: aha that solved!!! Many Thanks man....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was the fact that you are making a class named `Animator`. However there is an animator class already provided by `Unity`. When you declare an object of type `Animator` (`Animator myAnimator;`), the compiler thinks of your class instead of the class provided by `Unity`. And in your class there is no `IsInTransition()` method to use. 
To fix this simply rename your class to `MyAnimator` for example.